# Cmd exit status 1 error when installing Scrapy and pyOpenSSL

Tags: python, installation, scrapy

I am trying to install scrapy and have so far installed the dependancies Twisted Matrix, OpenSSL, and maybe one or two others. I'm using easy install and when i enter the command

```
easy_install Scrapy
```

i get this error.

```
C:\Users\Joel>easy_install Scrapy
Searching for Scrapy
Best match: scrapy 0.24.2
Processing scrapy-0.24.2-py2.7.egg
scrapy 0.24.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing scrapy script to C:\Users\Joel\Anaconda\Scripts
Installing scrapy.bat script to C:\Users\Joel\Anaconda\Scripts

Using c:\users\joel\anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for Scrapy
Searching for cryptography>=0.2.1
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/cryptography/
Best match: cryptography 0.5.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cryptography/cryptography-
0.5.3.tar.gz#md5=51a6a303bf35bf2bd18de6a51277020b
Processing cryptography-0.5.3.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\joel\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-cxadua\cryptography-0.5.3\
setup.cfg
Running cryptography-0.5.3\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\joel\appdat
a\local\temp\easy_install-cxadua\cryptography-0.5.3\egg-dist-tmp-mbuamd
Searching for cffi>=0.8
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/
Best match: cffi 0.8.6
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.6.tar.gz#md5
=474b5a68299a6f05009171de1dc91be6
Processing cffi-0.8.6.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\joel\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-cxadua\cryptography-0.5.3\
temp\easy_install-autsix\cffi-0.8.6\setup.cfg
Running cffi-0.8.6\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\joel\appdata\local\
temp\easy_install-cxadua\cryptography-0.5.3\temp\easy_install-autsix\cffi-0.8.6\
egg-dist-tmp-2x2ty5
c/_cffi_backend.c: In function 'convert_array_from_object':
c/_cffi_backend.c:1130:26: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1130:26: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extr
a-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1155:30: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1155:30: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extr
a-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1175:30: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1175:30: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extr
a-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c: In function 'convert_struct_from_object':
c/_cffi_backend.c:1208:26: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1208:26: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extr
a-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1221:30: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1221:30: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extr
a-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c: In function 'cdata_repr':
c/_cffi_backend.c:1608:13: warning: unknown conversion type character 'L' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1608:13: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extr
a-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1620:9: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in form
at [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1620:9: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra
-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c: In function 'cdataowning_repr':
c/_cffi_backend.c:1672:30: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1672:30: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extr
a-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c: In function '_cdata_get_indexed_ptr':
c/_cffi_backend.c:1845:26: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1845:26: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1845:26: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extr
a-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c: In function '_cdata_getslicearg':
c/_cffi_backend.c:1897:26: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1897:26: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1897:26: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extr
a-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c: In function 'cdata_ass_slice':
c/_cffi_backend.c:1976:26: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1976:26: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1976:26: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extr
a-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1994:30: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1994:30: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:1994:30: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extr
a-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c:2008:22: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:2008:22: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extr
a-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c: In function 'cdata_call':
c/_cffi_backend.c:2392:30: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:2392:30: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *
', but argument 3 has type 'Py_ssize_t' [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:2392:30: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extr
a-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c: In function 'cast_to_integer_or_char':
c/_cffi_backend.c:2941:26: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:2941:26: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *
', but argument 3 has type 'Py_ssize_t' [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:2941:26: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extr
a-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c:2953:26: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:2953:26: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *
', but argument 3 has type 'Py_ssize_t' [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:2953:26: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extr
a-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c: In function 'new_array_type':
c/_cffi_backend.c:3505:9: warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in form
at [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:3505:9: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra
-args]
c/_cffi_backend.c: In function 'b_complete_struct_or_union':
c/_cffi_backend.c:3934:22: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:3934:22: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in for
mat [-Wformat]
c/_cffi_backend.c:3934:22: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extr
a-args]
In file included from c/libffi_msvc/ffi.h:63:0,
             from c/libffi_msvc\ffi.c:29:
c/libffi_msvc/ffitarget.h:42:32: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attr
ibute__' before 'ffi_arg'
In file included from c/libffi_msvc\ffi.c:29:0:
c/libffi_msvc/ffi.h:185:3: error: unknown type name 'ffi_arg'
c/libffi_msvc\ffi.c: In function 'ffi_closure_SYSV':
c/libffi_msvc\ffi.c:257:18: warning: variable 'rtype' set but not used [-Wunused
-but-set-variable]
c/libffi_msvc\ffi.c: In function 'ffi_prep_closure_loc':
c/libffi_msvc\ffi.c:409:9: warning: variable 'bytes' set but not used [-Wunused-
but-set-variable]
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Users\\Joel\\Anaconda\\Scrip
ts\\gcc.bat' failed with exit status 1
```

also, I tried reinstalling the dependencies and when I tried to install pyOpenSSL using

```
easy_install pyOpenSSL
```

it gave me the same error.

can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I have used to install scrapy on multiple windows machines. Maybe they will help.

**Install python 2.7.x**

- put C:\python27 and C:\python27\scripts in your path

**Download and install pip:**

- Download get-pip.py (http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html)
- run: python get-pip.py

**Install Scrapy**

- pip install scrapy

**Download and install 2008 Visual C++ Redistributable (compiler)**

- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29

**Download pywin32 executable and install it**

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/